# How to create a LambdaExpression that copies all matching properties

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have made the basic stuff but I am stuck at creating the actually LambaExpresion:

Anyone have some pointers for what I want to write in the line with ? `var COPYEXPRESSION = ...`

```
public Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>> GetOrCreateMapExpression<TSource, TDestination>()
{
    return (Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>>)
        _expressionCache.GetOrAdd(new TypePair(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination)), tp =>
        {
            return CreateMapExpression(tp.SourceType, tp.DestinationType);
        });
}

private LambdaExpression CreateMapExpression(Type source, Type destination)
{
    ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(source);


   var sourceMembers =  source.GetProperties();
   var destMembers = destination.GetProperties();
   var matchingMembers = sourceMembers.Select(s =>
       new
       {
           Source = s,
           Dest = destMembers.FirstOrDefault(d =>
               d.Name.Equals(s.Name) && d.PropertyType == s.PropertyType)
       }).Where(map => map.Dest != null).ToArray();


  var COPYEXPRESSION = ...

    return Expression.Lambda(COPYEXPRESSION , instanceParameter);
}
```

## Update

I have gotten the return type correct, but when unit testing this, the mapped classes are having null on the properties.

```
private LambdaExpression CreateMapExpression(Type source, Type destination)
{
    ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(source);
    var instance2Parameter = Expression.New(destination);
    LabelTarget returnTarget = Expression.Label(destination);

    var sourceMembers = source.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic);
    var destMembers = destination.GetProperties().Where(p => p.SetMethod.IsPublic);
    var matchingMembers = sourceMembers.Select(s =>
        new
        {
            Source = s,
            Dest = destMembers.FirstOrDefault(d =>
                d.Name.Equals(s.Name) && d.PropertyType == s.PropertyType)
        }).Where(map => map.Dest != null).ToArray();

    var block = Expression.Block(Expression.Block(
        matchingMembers.Select(p =>
            Expression.Assign(
                Expression.Property(instance2Parameter, p.Dest),
                Expression.Property(instanceParameter, p.Source)))),
                 Expression.Label(returnTarget, instance2Parameter));


    return Expression.Lambda(block, instanceParameter);
}
```

## Solution

This worked for me:

```
    return Expression.Lambda( Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(destination),
        matchingMembers.Select(p =>
            Expression.Bind(p.Dest, Expression.Property(instanceParameter, p.Source)))),
            instanceParameter);
```

Comment: You don't need `d.Name.Equals(s.Name)` to compare two strings... `d.Name == s.Name` is enough (and it's more readable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(source);
ParameterExpression instance2Parameter = Expression.Parameter(destination);
```

you need TWO parameters, one for the source and one for the destination...

UNLESS you are building a new destination, then you need an `Expression.Variable` for `instance2Parameter` where you'll put the `Expression.New`

```
var block = Expression.Block(
                matchingMembers.Select(p =>       
                    Expression.Assign(
                        Expression.Property(instance2Parameter, p.Dest),
                        Expression.Property(instanceParameter, p.Source)))
```

This is a block containing all the `Expression.Assign`

Note that you should check for the presence of a setter in `Dest` and for a getter in `Source` (but it's probably better to do it in the `sourceMembers.Select`.)

Comment: Thanks, will try this when I am off the clock :)

Comment: I am missing the return part i think. It should be a Func<Source,Dest>, so letting instance2Paramter being a Expression.New innstead let me create the object, but i need to return that after the methods have been copyed.